# I want to convert HTML to pdf using Itext. Itext is converting HTML to pdf but it is not printing Hindi characters into PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Following is my Java Code to convert html into pdf it is creating PDF but didn't write Hindi Characters into PDF.

```
String mergedFileName = "E:\\Testing.html";
        
        String filePath="E:\\TestingPDF-24.pdf";

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));

        document.open();

        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.register(FONT);
        FontFactory.setFontImp(fontProvider);

        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer,document, new FileInputStream(mergedFileName),null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"),fontProvider);

        document.close();

System.out.println("Created");
```

I want to convert following HTML into PDF:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>लोरम इप्सम डोलर अमेट, क्यू सह कमर्ट पैट्रिओक, आईडी एस्ट डिकंट वोकेंट कैटरोस। Ex eam facer quando, sed autem consul quodsi cu। नीक यूरोप म्यूट वर्जिन। क्यूई डिको एन्टोपम आईडी, विज़ ते गेको इन्विनियर, लेगेरे सेम्पर सिट एक्स। मेल ईयूस कमोडो एट। ते यूसु
    वेरिटास रिप्रेंडेंट। बैठो परफेक्ट इमोक्टम इराकुंडिया क्यू। पूर्व तन्तास फैबेलस बैठो, इदिक अलिप्रैक्ट एरीपिट एट एस्ट, मलोरम सेपरेट ए सेड। क्वास ऑडायर एलिकिड ईडी, होमरो पूर्णांक ईम ईई है। विम जहां लेग्रे ओम्स्केक नं।</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you specify what is the value of "FONT' variable?

Comment: public static final String FONT = "font/ArialUnicodeMS.TTF"